# maven-war-plugin ignores user property war.warName

Tags: java, maven, war

If I add the following property in my POM, the `maven-war-plugin` uses it correctly:

```
<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

However if I add the following property the plugin ignores it (the generated WAR has the default name, i.e. artifactId-version):

```
<properties>
    <war.warName>${project.artifactId}</war.warName>
</properties>
```

Here are two excerpts from the `maven-war-plugin` documentation:

**warName:**

- The name of the generated WAR.
- Type: java.lang.String
- Required: Yes
- User Property: **war.warName**
- Default: ${project.build.finalName}

**failOnMissingWebXml:**

- Whether or not to fail the build if the web.xml file is missing. Set to false if you want you WAR built without a web.xml file. This may be useful if you are building an overlay that has no web.xml file.
- Type: boolean
- Since: 2.1-alpha-2
- Required: No
- User Property: **failOnMissingWebXml**
- Default: true

(Source: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html)

Why is the behavior different between `failOnMissingWebXml` and `war.warName`?

Also, if other plugins can use the value `${project.build.sourceEncoding}` why can't `maven-war-plugin` use the value of ${project.build.finalName}?

```
<properties>
    <!-- plugins use these values correctly -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

    <!-- not "found" by maven-war-plugin -->
    <war.warName>${project.artifactId}</war.warName>
    <project.build.finalName>${project.artifactId}</project.build.finalName>
</properties>
```

Thanks a lot! :)

EDIT: Since the version 2.4 of `maven-war-plugin` war.warName works as expected, however I still don't understand why setting `project.build.finalName` doesn't work.

Comment: which version of the maven war plugin are you using?

Comment: Ha! I didn't have anything in <build> so the default version that maven uses is 2.2. I've force it to use the 2.6 and war.warName is used correctly... Thanks. Their documentation should be updated though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply that you mistaken property cause `user property` is meant to be used usually from command like this:

```
mvn -Dwar.warName=xxx war:war
```

If you like to use it in a pom file you have to use it like this:

```xml
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warName>WhatEverYouLike</warName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
```

And you shouldn't use properties in your pom to define such things. Better use the configuration tag for this.

The  `${project.build.finalName}` should be used like this:

```xml
<project..>
  <build>
    <finalName>WhatYouLIke</finalName>
    ..
  </build>
</project>
```

The structure can be seen if you look into the [maven model](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html).

The usage of `${project.build.sourceEncoding}` is simply a convention in Maven plugins so you could define that property which is picked up by a larger number of plugins to be used for source encoding (I have to admit this is a little bit misleading). The original idea behind was having something in the maven model to represent the encoding which would mean to change it which is not really possible at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now.

Comment: I don't agree that user proerties are meant to be used from the command line only. Because the same mechanism applies to `maven.compiler.source` for example. It's set in the properties section and is evaluated by the maven-compiler-plugin. The `war.warName` user property is indeed not considered by the maven-war-plugin and is not even mentioned in teh documentation of newer plugin versions like 3.1.0.

Comment: The thing with `war.WarName` is simple that it had been [removed with version 3+](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MWAR/versions/12331760). Apart from that the intention is to have some properties only for convenience for example `maven.compiler.target`, `maven.compiler.source`..but they are not even correct nor consistence cause settings `target/source` is not enough ..

Comment: finalName is better as changing warName results a warning: "Parameter 'warName' is read-only, must not be used in configuration"